# Why can’t I enter a new name after my while loop is finished?

Tags: average, pascal

Why can’t I enter a new name after my while loop is finished? The loop should ask for a new name and it should until terminated, but it doesn’t do that. Why?

I was trying to create a program to read the student name and ID for a student as well as finding their average and finally outputting the ID and name with the title they relieved as a result of their average.

```pascal
program Students_of_ABC_Highschool;

var 
ID:integer;
studentname:string;
Mathmark:integer;
ITmark:integer;
Englishmark:integer;
Chemistrymark:integer;
Spanishmark:integer;
Frenchmark:integer;
Averagemark:integer;


begin

Averagemark:= 0;
Mathmark:=0;
ITmark:=0;
Englishmark:=0;
Chemistrymark:=0;
Spanishmark:=0;
Frenchmark:=0; 


while Averagemark <101 do begin 

writeln (' Please enter a student name ');
read (studentname);

writeln ('Please enter students ID: ');
read (ID);

writeln ('Please enter Math mark ');

  read (Mathmark);
  writeln ('Please enter IT mark ');
  
  read (ITmark);
  writeln ('Please enter English mark ');
  
  read (Englishmark);
  writeln ('Please enter Chemistry mark ');
  
  read (Chemistrymark);
  writeln ('Please enter Spanish mark ');
  
  read (Spanishmark);
  writeln ('Please enter French mark ');
  read (Frenchmark);
  
Averagemark:= (Mathmark + ITmark + Englishmark + Chemistrymark + Frenchmark +
     Spanishmark) div 6;
  writeln (' Average mark for student is ', Averagemark);
  
  if Averagemark >=60 then begin
  
      writeln ('Congratulations you are invited to the award ceremony ',studentname);
  end
  else
    begin writeln ('You are encouraged to work harder ', studentname);

  end;
  end;
  end.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading and processing file in Pascal won't work after first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970968/reading-and-processing-file-in-pascal-wont-work-after-first-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are employing `read` instead of `readLn`.
If you have a look into ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal”, you will find the following note:

> e) If `v` is a *variable‑access* possessing a *fixed‑string‑type* of capacity `c`, `read(f, v)` shall satisfy the following requirements. [… super technical mumbo jumbo …]
>
> NOTE — 6 If `eoln(f)` is initially `true`, then no characters are read, and the value of each component of `v` is a space.

Bottom line, you can “fix” your `program` by inserting the following conditional `readLn` which will “consume” any “remnant” *end‑of‑line* character prior your actual `read`:

```pascal
writeln (' Please enter a student name ');
if EOLn then
begin
    readLn
end;
read (studentname);
```

<sub>For the record: This is mostly a copy of [an earlier answer of mine](/a/68920150/9636977).</sub>